# How can I prove that the linear transformation has at most one non-zero eigen value?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

[image: the]

**My Attempt**: If $0$  was not an eigenvalue of $T$ then the eigenvalues of $T^k$ would have been non-zero also, $\ker(T^n) = \ker(T^{n-1})  = \mathbf{0}$.

Am I correct?

Can anyone please help me with **(b)**?

Comment: Is $n$ the dimension of $V $?

Comment: I think so. Otherwise , it will not make sense.

Comment: Consider $v$ such that $T^{n-2}(v)\neq0$ and $T^{n-1}(v)=0$. Then $T^{n-1}(v)=T(T^{n-2}(v))=0\times T^{n-2}(v)=0$

Comment: Can you please write it down in answer?@Gio

Comment: I did not get your comment..@Gio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a)** : Because $\mathrm{Ker}(T^{n-2}) \subset \mathrm{Ker}(T^{n-1})$, the hypothesis can be rewritten as : $\exists x \in \mathrm{Ker}(T^{n-1}) \setminus \mathrm{Ker}(T^{n-2})$. For such a $x$, you have $T^{n-2}x \neq 0$, and $T(T^{n-2}x)=0$, so $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ (and $T^{n-2}x$ an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $0$).

**(b)** : For this part, I would use the classical result on iterated kernels. If $\mathrm{Ker}(T^{n-2})  \varsubsetneq \mathrm{Ker}(T^{n-1})$, that means that
$$\lbrace 0 \rbrace \varsubsetneq \mathrm{Ker}(T) \varsubsetneq ... \varsubsetneq \mathrm{Ker}(T^{n-2})  \varsubsetneq \mathrm{Ker}(T^{n-1})$$

You deduce that $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Ker}(T^{n-1})) \geq n-1$. You can see (by trigonalizing $T$ for example), that $T$ cannot have more than one non-zero eigenvalue.

Comment: What is $n$ in your answer?@TheSilverDoe

Comment: The dimension of $V$.

Comment: Then how are you getting $\mathrm{Ker}(T) \varsubsetneq {Ker}(T^2) $ ?

Comment: Please see the  second line of (b) @TheSilverDoe

Comment: I am using a classical result on the kernels : it says that the sequence $\mathrm{Ker}(T^k)$, for any endomorphism $T$, is strictly increasing, then stationnary. So here, the hypothesis that $\mathrm{Ker}(T^{n-2})  \varsubsetneq \mathrm{Ker}(T^{n-1})$ implies that the sequence is strictly increasing before the power $n-1$.